# Ubuntu 19.10: "Add" OpenVPN connection is grayed out

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to add a new OpenVPN connection on a fully-updated Ubuntu 19.10 PC, but the `Add` button uptop is grayed out:

[image]

[image]

I already tried to:

```
zane@zane-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-openvpn is already the newest version (1.8.10-1).
network-manager-openvpn-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.10-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
zane@zane-pc:~$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager
zane@zane-pc:~$ sudo service openvpn restart
```

What else?

Comment: When you hover the mouse over the greyed-out "Add", what does it tell you?

Comment: Add a name and a CA cert.

Comment: @Sebastian on hover, it doesn't "tell" me anything. It's more of a whisper: "Go back to Windows", I hear :-)

Comment: @heynnema name is set. CA certificate.... where (path) do I select it from?

Comment: Is "VPN 1" something YOU set, or was it already there when you started? The CA certificate path is wherever you saved it. Are you trying to create a VPN to your ISP, or something else? Do they use OpenVPN?

Comment: When I hover over the "Save" button in my interface, it shows a popup telling me the certificate is invalid. So you would need to add a certificate.